# Can you declare a type whose index signature is based on a variable?

Tags: typescript

I'm making an API call that is of the format `url/ids=[id1,id2,id3]` and returns an object of the form `{ id1: {...}, id2: {...}, id3: {...} }`

I can type this as `interface ApiResponse { [key: number]: ResponseShape }`, but I actually have more type information than that, as that type loses the relationship between the inputted ids and the response object's keys.

Is there a way to use the *variable* ids in the type? I know TS is compile time, but I was hoping I for the following scenario:

```
function apiCall(ids: number[]) {
  const someRandomNumber = 10;
  fetch('url').then(
    res => {
      const data = res.json() as ApiResponse<ids>;
      // fine to access by the id
      const works = data[ids[0]];
      
      // undefined, because 5 isn't one of the ids we requested so won't be in the reponse type.
      const wontWork = data[someRandomNumber]
    }
  );
}
```

I'm guessing this doesn't exist since it's pretty niche and right on the border of what should happen at compile time, but I'm hoping there's a way to do `type ApiResponse<T extends number[]> = { [id in T[number]]: ResponseShape }` and pass the ids parameter in as a type

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/w2469m) meet your needs? Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/WJ49VN) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Ooh, never mind, [this answer](https://tsplay.dev/w2469m) is doing the same thing.  *Still*, it would be good if you could fix up that example code so that only the problem you're asking about is present.  `cons` is not a thing, `then(res: ApiResponse<ids> => {` is not valid even if `ids` were a type, you seem to have forgotten that you need to call `json()` in there somewhere, etc.

Comment: This wasn't meant to be a minimal reproducible example since I didn't expect people to actually play around with the code, the code was just there as a visual example.

I won't fix this up now since it's already been answered but thanks for your answer!

Comment: Well, could you improve it to be a [mre] so that the question/answer pair can serve to help future readers more?  If the question isn't about syntax errors, then the presence of syntax errors can only distract from the issue.  It's great that you got the help you wanted; improving the question would be helping others as well.

Comment: Fixed it up so all that doesn't work is the type itself just in case anyone does want to play around and not skip straight to the answer, thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make `apiCall` generic and then use `T[number]` to get a union of all the passed IDs, you can then construct a Record where the keys are those numbers.

```
type ApiResponse<T extends number> = Record<T, 'foo'>;
function apiCall<T extends readonly number[]>(ids: T) {
  return fetch('url')
    .then(res => res.json()) as Promise<ApiResponse<T[number]>>;
}
apiCall([1, 2] as const)
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result[1]); // Allowed
    console.log(result[3]); // Not allowed
  });
```

You'll have to be sure to pass a tuple (like `[1, 2] as const`) and not a `number[]` for the type of the individual IDs to be preserved across the script.

Comment: Perfect! Don't know why I couldn't think of that, thank you.